# date range prompting modal cant use as variables within said modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

on my booking page I select 2 date ranges which then presents the modal popup. I am trying to work within the modal the 2 date ranges (ie the days between them, booking start day etc).

Doing this within the main page is fine, but my values are not working within the modal popup. I think it is because the values I need to work with are the ones that are actually prompting the popup.

```
<!-- Modal -->


<div class="modal fade" id="owner_price_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog custom_price_dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header"> 
              <button type="button" id="close_custom_price_internal" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h2 class="modal-title_big"><?php esc_html_e('Custom Price','wprentals');?></h2>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php esc_html_e('Set custom price for selected period - test','wprentals');?></h4>
            </div>


            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="booking_form_request_mess_modal"></div>    

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="start_date_owner_book"><?php esc_html_e('Start Date','wprentals');?></label>
                        <input type="text" id="start_date_owner_book" size="40" name="booking_from_date" class="form-control" value="">




                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="end_date_owner_book"><?php  esc_html_e('End Date','wprentals');?></label>
                        <input type="text" id="end_date_owner_book" size="40" name="booking_to_date" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>


                    <input type="hidden" id="property_id" name="property_id" value="" />
                    <input name="prop_id" type="hidden"  id="agent_property_id" value="">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="coment"><?php echo esc_html__( 'New Price in ','wprentals').' '.esc_html($wp_estate_currency_symbol);?></label>
                        <input type="text" id="new_custom_price" size="40" name="new_custom_price" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>    


                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="period_extra_price_per_guest"><?php echo wpestate_show_labels('extra_price_per_guest',$rental_type,$booking_type).' '.esc_html($wp_estate_currency_symbol);?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="period_extra_price_per_guest" size="40" name="period_extra_price_per_guest" class="form-control" value="0">
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="period_week_price"><?php  echo wpestate_show_labels('price_week_label',$rental_type,$booking_type);?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="period_week_price" size="40" name="period_week_price" class="form-control" value="">
                </div> 

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="period_month_price"><?php echo wpestate_show_labels('price_month_label',$rental_type,$booking_type);?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="period_month_price" size="40" name="period_month_price" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>       

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="period_price_per_weekeend"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Price per weekend in ','wprentals').' '.esc_html($wp_estate_currency_symbol);?></label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="period_price_per_weekeend" size="40" name="period_price_per_weekeend" class="form-control" value="">



                </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="period_min_days_booking"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Minimum days of booking','wprentals');?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="period_min_days_booking" size="40" name="period_min_days_booking" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>




                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="period_checkin_change_over"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Allow only bookings starting with the check in on changeover days','wprentals');?></label>
                    <select id="period_checkin_change_over" name="period_checkin_change_over" class="select-submit2">
                        <?php 
                        foreach($week_days as $key=>$value){
                            print '   <option value="'.esc_attr($key).'">'.esc_html($value).'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <?php
                $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( "wprentals_custom_price_nonce" );
                print'<input type="hidden" id="wprentals_custom_price" value="'.esc_html($ajax_nonce).'" />    ';
                ?>

                <button type="submit" id="set_price_dates" class="wpb_button  wpb_btn-info  wpb_regularsize   wpestate_vc_button  vc_button"><?php esc_html_e('Set price for period','wprentals');?></button>


            </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I had feedback that it is as simple as the below, however although this works in the main page (just for test purposes) it does not work within the modal.  Inside the modal I get invalid date which I believe is because the start_date_owner_book and end_date_owner_book are coming back as empty values when the modal is first loaded.

```
var startDate = new Date($("#start_date_owner_book").val());
var endDate = new Date($("#end_date_owner_book").val());

var timeDifference = endDate - startDate;
var differenceInDays = timeDifference / (1000*3600*24);
$("#period_min_days_booking").val(Math.floor(differenceInDays));
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Warm regards

Answer (score 0):

First disable select2 in your two date selects and see yet returns empty. If you detect that select2 causing the problem, remove `tabindex="-1"`attribute in the modal group tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks cassiolacerda.

It was because i was trying to make a date on the first 2 lines, that input was uk format so it was giving an error whenever the day value (on my field it was dd-mm-yyyy) was over 13 or over.  I had to split it down first, then reconstruct it then get the date.